# useEffect with async function to play sound not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to play background music in a React Native/Expo app as soon as the homeScreen loads.

Using expo AV library, I set up a MusicContext with a method to start the music. Here is my MusicContext.js

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
} from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { Audio } from "expo-av"

const initialState = {
  playMusic: false,
  setPlayMusic: () => null,
}

export const MusicContext = React.createContext(initialState)

const startMusic = async () => {
  let mainTheme = null

  if (!mainTheme) {
    mainTheme = new Audio.Sound() 
  try {
    console.log("trying")
    await mainTheme.loadAsync(require("../assets/sounds/MainTheme.mp3"))
    mainTheme.setStatusAsync({ isLooping: true })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Couldnt load main theme")
    return
  }
}
}

export const MusicProvider = props => {
  const [playMusic, setPlayMusic] = useState(initialState.playMusic)

  return (
    <MusicContext.Provider
      value={{
        playMusic,
        setPlayMusic,
        startMusic,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MusicContext.Provider>
  )
}

MusicContext.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

I then call the the `startMusic` method in `useEffect` on my home screen.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { startMusic } = useContext(MusicContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("running")
    startMusic()
  }, [])
```

I see all of the console.log output so I know it is running, but the music never plays. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the audio code work outside of this hook? If you run the few lines in the console, does the music work as expected?

Comment: @RossAllen yes it does, so I believe the issues lies in trying to use async within useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't putting the `startMusic` in `initialState`?

When I put the function in the `initalState`, it gets called properly.

To answer your question more generally, you either need to wrap an aysnc function in an IIFE or have it as a separate function that is called.

I usually wrap as IIFE.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy thanks for your answer. I did move it to initial state but it's still not playing the music. The function is running because the console.log output is showing up, it's just that the music doesn't play. Were you able to get a sound file to play?

Comment: No. I left that package out and focused on the function calls. Async calls from useEffect are okay in general. I do them all of the time. It’s just the the first argument for useEffect can’t be async. You have to wrap async code in an IIFE or call a separate async function, as you are doing. I’ll look at that package a little more closely later today and see if there’s something else that may be missing.

Comment: I got the music to play by adding `mainTheme.playAsync();` after the `setStausAsync` call. Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy that was it!